# Is there a graceful way to refactor a namespace collision with Ruby/Rails gems?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

I would like to use the Ruby gem [Turn](https://github.com/TwP/turn/issues), but it currently collides with a model (ActiveRecord) I have called 'Turn'. The end result is that my test output is borked.

I realize I can simply refactor my model, but I'm wondering if there's a graceful way I can namespace the gem without having to touch my model.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to influence which modules (namespaces) a gem will use. Files that are required by Ruby will always be evaluated in the global scope.

It's best practice for gem authors to use a module with the same name of the gem, so usually you know what to expect when you install a gem.

Apart from not using Turn, the only solutions are to change your model's name or place it inside a namespace.